# neo4j: user defined procedure AuthorizationViolationException after upgrading from 3.0.7 => 3.1.2

Tags: neo4j

I have written a used defined procedure that runs fine under 3.0.7.

I just upgraded neo4j from 3.0.7 to 3.1.2.

As required, I replaced "@PerformsWrite" with "mode=WRITE" (in the @Procedure annotation)

When I call createNode(), it fails with "AuthorizationViolationException: Token create operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with roles [admin] restricted to WRITE."

I am able to create nodes in the graph via the neo4j browser, just not via my procedure.  The procedure is being called in the context of the "neo4j" login.

Is there any additional config/setup that I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a well meant, temporary change which will be rolled back in 3.1.3

Until then you can use this setting in your neo4j.conf

`dbms.security.allow_publisher_create_token=true`

Sorry for the inconvenience.